# Where should Exceptions be caught?

Tags: oop

In designing class with multiple/nested has-a relationships, who should catch exceptions?
I guess this depends on design but is there any rule of thumb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule of thumb is *the one who knows better what to do with that exception should catch the exception*.

Comment: So the next question is how do u determine who knows better :)

Comment: @user386338: That's easy. Some class catches the exception and... what does it do? If it can only show an error message that's obviously the wrong class - the same could have been achieved by handling all exceptions on the top level.